# TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, python-unicode

I'm trying import a text file and save it on my desktop, but the text is in "utf-8" (there is this information in the book), so when I save without encoding the text has many strange characters, but when I try to save with explicit encoding this error appears:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Unidas/Semestre/ABC/8.1.py", line 14, in n_palabras
>
> libro.write(archivo.read())
>
> TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
> ```

The code:

```
def n_palabras(x):
    import urllib2
    import io
    import string

    archivo = urllib2.urlopen(x)
    libro = io.open("alice.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
    libro.write(archivo.read())
    libro.close()
```

How can I save this file with encoding utf-8? 
I'm using Pycharm with Python 2.7

Comment: If you get this error message, it may be a python 2 vs. 3 issue. It was for me at least.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that `urlopen` returns a bytes-oriented file-like object, while `io.open` expects true text inputs (where "text" means "`unicode` on Python 2, `str` on Python 3").

The only thing you need to change is to `decode` the result of calling `read`; it's bytes-like by default, and you need true text. You need to figure out the correct encoding (either hard-coding it, or explicitly inspecting the headers to figure it out) to decode it correctly (it's likely either UTF-8 or, much less likely, cp1252, but it could be something weird).

In any event, knowing that, the only change you'd need to make is to change:

```
libro.write(archivo.read())
```

to:

```
libro.write(archivo.read().decode(knownencoding))
```

If you're pretty sure the server is always providing UTF-8 output, then:

```
libro.write(archivo.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

is sufficient. Yes, it's mildly wasteful (you decode it only to write it to a stream that immediately reencodes it), but importantly, this gives you a guarantee that the bytes you received were interpretable as valid UTF-8, which dumping the raw bytes to disk won't guarantee.

A more elaborate solution inspects the headers:

```
import urllib2
import io
import string

def n_palabras(x):
    archivo = urllib2.urlopen(x)

    # Find charset in headers, if it exists    
    for p in archivo.headers.plist:
        key, sep, value = p.partition('=')
        if sep and key.strip().lower() == 'charset':
           encoding = value.strip()
           break
    else:
        encoding = 'utf-8'

    data = archivo.read()

    try:
        # Try to use parsed charset
        data = data.decode(encoding)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # If that fails, try UTF-8 as fallback; let exception bubble
        # if this fails too
        data = data.decode('utf-8')

    with io.open("alice.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as libro:
        libro.write(data)
```